# How to set Asana so emailed-in Tasks are brought to my attention when I log in, without manually searching for them each time?

Tags: asana

I just started using Asana to manage bug fixes/feature requests from my clients, and I can't hardly believe that every single time I open it I need to manually ask it to show me unassigned tasks and assign them by hand to myself to get them to appear on the My Tasks view. Anything coming in by email (which is how I'm going to have my clients do it) is unassigned, and Asana gives me absolutely no clue when I log in if an unassigned task is waiting for me to assign it, and it will remain hidden from my to-do list (the My Tasks view) until I do.

There are existing solutions on SO for how to search to find unassigned tasks; those are not what I'm after, as those are how to do manual one-time searches, but I want Asana to tell me the things I need to know about *without* me either having to remember to manually ask for them every single time I log in, or risking missing something time-sensitive.

Alternatively, if it would either automagically assign mailed-in tasks to me, or let me set my "All Tasks" bookmark to be the default view as soon as I log in, either of these would suffice. I can't find any way of doing any of these things—my goal is that 100% of user-submitted tasks be brought to my attention without me having to remember to look for them (otherwise I could just stick with my dubious previous system of remembering to search my email inboxes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using one email address to assign tasks (from a form or whatever) you can go to account settings -> from email and add your email address. That will automatically assign those tasks to you.

Here's the asana docs for it: https://asana.com/guide/help/email/email-to-asana

Otherwise, you can use Zapier (or similar service) to manage creating tasks via email for you if you'd prefer not mess around with the API.

Comment: Right you are. I can't figure why it didn't seem to work yesterday, but I just tried it, and it works exactly as you describe. Thanks!